# Get an xml element inside an element trought adapter using SoapUI

Tags: android, xml, webserver, soapui

My problem is the following, I have this service in soap

this is the request:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:altaPlazoFijo>
         <nroLlamada>2</nroLlamada>
         <matricula>3453269</matricula>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tipo>P</tipo>
         <importe>1000</importe>
         <plazo>35</plazo>
         <tipoOrden>2</tipoOrden>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <codigoRenovacion>DE</codigoRenovacion>
         <planRenovacion></planRenovacion>
         <cuentaDeposito>3453269100</cuentaDeposito>
         <nroDocumento></nroDocumento>
         <cuentaOrigen></cuentaOrigen>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <listaOrdenesReciprocas>
            <!--Optional:-->

            <matricula></matricula>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nombre></nombre>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nroDoc></nroDoc>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tipoDoc></tipoDoc>
         </listaOrdenesReciprocas>
      </ser:altaPlazoFijo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is the response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
              <ns2:altaPlazoFijoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.transferencias.webServices.smsv.com.ar/">
                 <return>
                    <plazoFijoExtendido>
                       <fechaDeposito>06/12/2016</fechaDeposito>
                       <fechaVencimiento>10/01/2017</fechaVencimiento>
                       <filialPlazoFijo>CASA CENTRAL</filialPlazoFijo>
                       <interesPlazoFijo>19.18</interesPlazoFijo>
                       <montoPlazoFijo>1019.18</montoPlazoFijo>
                       <nvoNroCertificado>0000000</nvoNroCertificado>
                       <tasaPlazoFijo>02000</tasaPlazoFijo>
                       <cuentaDepositoRenovacion>0</cuentaDepositoRenovacion>
                    </plazoFijoExtendido>
                 </return>
              </ns2:altaPlazoFijoResponse>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to try to initialize every element in that service with the right information so I can have a response, so I do this in this way matching every element with the params:

```
altaPlazoFijo: function(nroLlamada,userID,moneda,importe,plazo,tipoOrden,codRenovacion,cuentaDep,handler,onErrorHander){
        this.makeRequest('Transferencias', 'altaPlazoFijo',
                [{
                    "nroLlamada":nroLlamada,
                    "matricula":userID,
                    "tipo":moneda, 
                    "importe":importe, 
                    "plazo":plazo,
                    "tipoOrden":tipoOrden,
                    "codigoRenovacion":codRenovacion,
                    "cuentaDeposito":cuentaDep,
                    "listaOrdenesReciprocas":{
                        "matricula":0,
                        "nombre":"",
                        "nroDoc":0,
                        "tipoDoc":"",
                    },

                }],
                    handler, onErrorHander);
    },
```

and the problem is the element "listaOrdenesReciprocas", because its differences compared to the others, it is a list that can be repeated up until five times and has elements inside it like "matricula", "name", etc. My problem lies in I can't match my params to that elements, I can't get a way to get into "listaOrdenesReciprocas" and matching with "matricula", "name", "nroDoc", "tipoDoc". i have to initialize that elements becose in other ways they assigned as null, and the service responde is "java.null.pointerExeption".

If it is of any help I put the code of the adapter here:

---

```
function altaPlazoFijo(params){
    return makeRequest(getRawSoap("altaPlazoFijo", params));
}

function getRawSoap(action, params){
    var opening = [
        '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.transferencias.webServices.smsv.com.ar/">'
      , '<soapenv:Body>'
      , '<ser:'+action+'>'
    ] , middle  = [] 
      , closing = [
        '</ser:'+action+'>'
      , '</soapenv:Body>'
      , '</soapenv:Envelope>'
    ] , rawBody = '';


    //if the parameter is an object then use the object properies names as params for SOAP envelope

    if(params.lengh == undefined)
    {
        for(var name in params) {
            middle.push('<'+name+'>'+params[name]+'</'+name+'>');
        }

    }else{
        for(arg in params){
            var name = 'arg'+arg;
            middle.push('<'+name+'>'+params[arg]+'</'+name+'>');
        }
    }



    rawBody     = opening.concat(middle,closing).join("");

    WL.Logger.warn(rawBody);
    return rawBody;
}

function escapeSoapChars(toScape){
    return toScape.replace(/\//g,'\\/').replace(/"/g,'\\"');
}

function makeRequest(body, headers, soapAction){
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/WSTransferenciasWAS/TransferenciasService',
        body: {
            content : body, 
            contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }; 
    headers = headers || {};

    soapAction = soapAction || '';

    if (soapAction != 'null')
        headers.SOAPAction = soapAction;

    input['headers'] = headers;

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); 
}
```

Comment: Are you using soapui to test this? Becuase, it is not clear from the post.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code/xml. Instead add them directly to a code block in your post (as you have done further down). I have embedded the images for you, but it would be better if you could replace these with code blocks.

Comment: i am using soapui, yes